# grep utility in shell script

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to overcome a limitation on our file structure.  I want to grep a whole series of files in a known location. If I do a standard grep from command line

```
(grep -i searchpattern known_dir/s*.sql)
```

I get the following error:

```
ksh: /usr/bin/grep: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long.
```

so I have a little for loop that looks like:

```
searchfor=$1
for i in /$ENV_VAR_DIR/s*.sql
do
  grep -i $searchfor $i
done
```

When I execute this I get a couple problems:

1. it gives me the line of code but no file name I need both
2. `-l` obviously gives me just the path/filename I want to trim the path off I am just executing from my home directory.

Comment: This is a question about shell programming; it belongs on StackOverflow and not elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following:

```
$ find known_dir -name 's*.sql' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i searchpattern
```

With `xargs`, you can vary the maximum number of files you pass to `grep` each time using the `-n` option.

The `-print0` and `-0` options is a defense against spaces in filenames.

You could even compute multiple `grep` commands in parallel on multiple cores using `-P` option.

Comment: Add /dev/null after the search pattern and you get the file names (because there are always at least two files on the command line, /dev/null and whatever was found by find).

Comment: You can also use '-H' on some versions of 'grep' - but not all - to get the file names listed unconditionally.

Answer (score 2):

As a hack you could also specify /dev/null to your grep command to get -l to list a file, however your method is going to be slow as it uses shell looping and starts a grep process per file. `find` and `xargs` are your friend here as already mentioned.

Perhaps you could use the [findrepo](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo) script which seems to do as you require.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | read fname; do
    grep searchpattern $fname /dev/null
done
```

This does two things for you.

1. You don't need to expand all the files at once, it processes them one at a time.
2. By listing /dev/null as a second file it won't match anything but it will get grep to print the filename. Gnu grep has an option to force filename output but this will work on any unix.

The other traditional thing to do with this shell design pattern is to feed the loop with `find`.

```
find . -name "*.sql" | read fname; do
    grep searchpattern $fname /dev/null
done
```

You might also wants to make `searchpattern` be `$1`.

Comment: Beware pathnames with spaces!

Comment: True, every `$fname` should be `"$fname"` and the `"*.sql"` should be `'*.sql'`.

Answer (score 1):

find ./known_dir/ -name "s*.sql"|xargs grep -i searchpattern

Comment: sorry my mistake it is 
find  ./known_dir/ "s*.sql"|xargs grep -i searchpattern

Comment: Works like a charm! I know this is asking alot but now is there a way to trim off the directory path so all I have is the filename?

Comment: This works great I think Im good with what I have in the end here is what  I ended up with:
for i in $1
do
  find $i -name $2 | xargs grep -i $3
done

Comment: I still think you want ack or grin. Go try them out. I don't care about the "accept". :)

Answer (score 0):

`grep -H` will force the filename to be prepended to each output line, the same as it would be if you were doing the original single command.

The easiest way to get just the filename, whether from `-H` or `-l`, is to have the directory be your current working directory when you run the command:

```
searchfor=$1
cd /$ENV_VAR_DIR
for i in s*.sql
do
  grep -Hi $searchfor $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You want either [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) or [grin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin).

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install grin    
grin -I "*.sql" searchpattern
```

To only show file name

```
grin -I "*.sql" -l searchpattern
```