# find and copy file using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, copy, find

Anybody has an alternate way of finding and copying files in bash than:

```
find . -ctime -15 | awk '{print "cp " $1 " ../otherfolder/"}' | sh
```

I like this way because it's flexible, as I'm building my command (can by any command) and executing it after.

Are there other ways of streamlining commands to a list of files?

Thanks

Comment: Similar Q&A 1+1/2 years later: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5241625/1172302

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I would recommend using `find`'s `-exec` option:

`find . -ctime 15 -exec cp {} ../otherfolder \;`

As always, consult the manpage for best results.

Comment: The find man page suggests using single quotes around the braces since it may get misinterpreted without them.

Comment: You should replace `\;` with `+` to avoid running a `cp` every time.

Comment: @BroSlow Not sure why but this only works with \; and with + I get 'missing argument for -exec'.

Comment: what if all the files have the same name (`im.png`)? Can I put them in the same directory while renaming, such as `im_1.png`, `im_2.png`, `im_3.png`...

Comment: If found in subdirectories - copies to the root of `otherfolder` :(

Comment: @user234932 you need to use an alternate way to pass destination to `cp`: `find … -exec cp -t <target_directory> {} +` should work

Comment: @Mr.Tao This solution is ~3.5x faster than original solution.

Comment: On macos the "\;" solution works but the "{} +" not (for me).

Answer (score 17):

I usually use this one:

```
find . -ctime -15 -exec cp {} ../otherfolder/ \;
```

Answer (score 13):

If your `cp` is GNU's:

```
find . -ctime 15 -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 cp --target-directory=../otherfolder
```

Comment: With this syntax I get `cp: missing operand`.  If I use the syntax provided by @andrey-vlasovskikh (`-I{} -cp {} otherfolder`) I don't receive this error.

Comment: Updated the answer to cover that case (when `find` produces no output).

Comment: I like this. I added a `| head -z -n 10` after the find to limit my results.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with `xargs`:

```
$ find . -ctime 15 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} ../otherfolder
```

See also [grep utility in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544157/grep-utility-in-shell-script).

Comment: This has the advantage of being faster than `find -exec` because it doesn't create a new `cp` process for each file. However if you have GNU find you can do `find -exec ... +` instead of `find -exec ... ';'` for the same effect :)

Answer (score 4):

Use this for copy and many other things:

```
for f in $(find /apps -type f -name 'foo'); do cp ${f} ${f}.bak; cmd2; cmd3; done;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $ before (find /apps -type f -name 'foo')? Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

-exec is likely the way to go, unless you have far too many files. Then use xargs.

Comment: This could be a comment to an accepted response or supply examples for each method you've mentioned.