# Find and copy files

Tags: linux, copy, find

Why does the following does not copy the files to the destination folder?

```
# find /home/shantanu/processed/ -name '*2011*.xml' -exec cp /home/shantanu/tosend {} \;

cp: omitting directory `/home/shantanu/tosend'
cp: omitting directory `/home/shantanu/tosend'
cp: omitting directory `/home/shantanu/tosend'
```

Comment: Example how to copy files newer than date:  find . -type f -newermt '2022-10-20 00:00:00' -exec cp "{}" ..  \;

Answer (score 414, accepted):

If your intent is to copy the found files into `/home/shantanu/tosend`, you have the order of the arguments to `cp` reversed:

```
find /home/shantanu/processed/ -name '*2011*.xml' -exec cp "{}" /home/shantanu/tosend  \;
```

Please note: the `find` command uses `{}` as placeholder for the matched file.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\;`?

Comment: @Astrid check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Comment: `find -iname '*.mp3' -mtime -1 -exec cp {} /home/my_path/ \;` is there anything wrong with this command ? it's not working

Comment: Doesn't work if the results have a space in the path. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 the curly braces also have to be put into single quotes: find -iname '*.mp3' -mtime -1 -exec cp '{}' /home/my_path/ \;

Comment: Note:  This didn't work for me until I made sure there were two spaces before "\;"

Answer (score 49):

i faced an issue something like this...

Actually, in two ways you can process `find` command output in `copy` command

1. If `find` command's output doesn't contain any space i.e if file name doesn't contain space in it then you can use below mentioned command:

   Syntax: `find <Path> <Conditions> | xargs cp -t <copy file path>`

   Example: `find -mtime -1 -type f | xargs cp -t inner/`
2. But most of the time our production data files might contain space in it. So most of time below mentioned command is safer:

   Syntax: `find <path> <condition> -exec cp '{}' <copy path> \;`

   Example `find -mtime -1 -type f -exec cp '{}' inner/ \;`

In the second example, last part i.e semi-colon is also considered as part of `find` command, that should be escaped before press the enter button. Otherwise you will get an error something like this

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

In your case, **copy command syntax is wrong** in order to copy find file into `/home/shantanu/tosend`.  The following command will work:

```
find /home/shantanu/processed/ -name '*2011*.xml' -exec cp  {} /home/shantanu/tosend \;
```

Comment: 3. If you have GNU `find`/`xargs`, `find <Path> <Conditions> -print0 | xargs -0 -r cp -t <copy file path>`.  Example: `find -mtime -1 -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 cp -t inner/`

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `cp -t /home/shantanu/tosend` in order to tell it that the argument is the target directory and not a source. You can then change it to `-exec ... +` in order to get `cp` to copy as many files as possible at once.

Comment: In linux had to specify the target directory like so:  
`find /home/shantanu/processed/ -name '*2011*.xml' -exec cp --target-directory=/home/shantanu/tosend {} \;`

Comment: This answer could be improved and shortened if the complete command was provided like in the top answer.

Answer (score -4):

The reason for that error is that you are trying to copy a folder which requires -r option also to cp
Thanks

Comment: Hi, as question is already answered (from a while back) this isn't really a relevant answer, it also should be a comment (when you have some more rep), unless you wish to expand and explain it. Just a heads up :).

Answer (score -4):

```
for i in $(ls); do cp -r "$i" "$i"_dev; done;
```