# copy newest files to another directory via ssh

Tags: ssh, copy

I want to copy the files that were created during the last 3 days from one directory to another. 
I'm using the command `find . -mtime -3` to list the latest files but how do I copy then to another directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241677/163495) should help you

```
find . -mtime -3 -exec cp {} /destinationfolder  \;
```