# Find and copy all images from hard disk

Tags: linux, image, command-line, copy, find

I am trying to find all the images stored on my internal hard disk and copy them to an external USB drive.

I found this Linux command to find all the image files.  How can I add the copy command?

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file --mime-type | grep -i image
```

Comment: Should be on SuperUSer.com

Comment: Possible dup. of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file --mime-type | grep -i image | cut -f 1 -d : | xargs -I{} cp "{}" dest_dir
```