# Find and copy files with relative path

Tags: linux, copy, find

At this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files), it shows how to copy files and it will recurse into subdirectories to copy files. How do I copy files and include the relative path in the copy?

For instance,

`find /path/to/directory/or/just/dot -name '*somepartoffilename*' -exec cp {} /path/you/want/to/copy/to  \;`

So if you have `/path/to/directory/a/somepartoffilename.txt` and `/path/to/directory/b/somepartoffilename.txt`, you'll only end up with one of those files in `/path/you/want/to/copy/to`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$ tree
.   
├── a
│   └── foo
└── b
    └── foo

2 directories, 2 files
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'path={}; d=/tmp/dest/$(dirname $path); mkdir -p $d ; cp $path $d' \;
$ tree /tmp/dest/
/tmp/dest/
├── a
│   └── foo
└── b
    └── foo

2 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Cool, I think you can save on the `mkdir` by doing `--parents` to `cp` command also

Answer (score 4):

@Grapsus had a good answer, but it didn't work for files with spaces in them.  This one does :

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'path="{}"; d=/tmp/dest/$(dirname "$path"); mkdir -p "$d" ; cp "$path" "$d"' \;
```