# Copy Folders and its files with specific date in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

Is there a way to copy folders and its contents with specific modification date in Linux, for example I have this folder A and B it contains files with modified date `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-18`, is it possible to copy folder A and B containing only files modified on `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-08`?

I did some research and came up with this

```
find ./ -type d -exec mkdir -p {} $target{} \;
find $source -mtime +30 -exec cp -p "{}" $target \;
```

but after executing the 2nd line, files will be copied to the root directory on target location, not in the same structure as the source

for example i have this source directory to be copied on the target

```
/storage/subdir1/* (modified date range - 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-18)
/storage/subdir2/* (modified date range - 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-18)
/storage/subdir3/* (modified date range - 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-18)
/storage/subdir4/* (modified date range - 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-18)
```

would it be possible that in the target directory (/targetdir/) all sub directories will be created automatically and it contains only files with modified date (2015-01-01 to 2015-01-08)

John

Comment: my bad for not including some details, and now i already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work.

```
find A -mtime -18 -mtime +1 -exec cp \{\} B/ \;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, though i use rsync to ahieve my goal
`find A/ -mtime -18 -mtime +1 -exec rsync -auvrp \{\} B/ \;` this will copy its parent directory and its sub directory containing files with specified date within its original directory. thumbs up @Karthikeyan.R.S

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `find`.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files), you can copy files using `find` like this:

```
find /home/shantanu/processed/ -name '*2011*.xml' -exec cp {} /home/shantanu/tosend  \;
```

Now what you need is to specify dates instead of a pattern in your `find` command, you can do it as:

```
find /path/to/source -newermt "Jan 1 2015" -and \! -newermt "Jan 10 2015" -exec cp {} /path/to/dest  \;
```

Comment: i tried this kind of command but what i want to achieve is on my edited post