# moving folder from unknown location to different location on server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I am trying to move a folder and his content to a different location on the server.
Folder can be anywhere but I have to move it to a specific location.
So far I have tried something like this, but its not working

`find / -name 'test_folder' -exec mv 'test_folder' /Users/michael/Downloads/here/. {} +`

Any suggestions, what am I doing wrong?

Also what would be variation of this command in `.sh` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: find and copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562102/bash-find-and-copy)

Comment: i need to move entire folder, not just his content tho

Comment: You have basically written `find <thing I don't know where it is> mv <thing I don't know where it is> to /Users/michael....` You want to tell it to `mv <result of find command> to /Users/michael....`. See chepner's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give `mv` the full name of the folder found, not just the immediate name: `/some/other/dir/test_folder`, not `test_folder`. Use

```
find / -name test_folder -exec mv '{}' /Users/michael/Downloads/here +
```

UPDATE: The `+` form of `-exec` seems to require that `{}` be the final argument of the command, unlike with the `;` version.

```
# Less efficient, as `mv` is called for every found directory
find / -name test_folder -exec mv '{}' /Users/michael/Downloads/here \;
```

or

```
# More complicated, but less overhead
find / -name test_folder -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" /Users/michael/Downloads/here' {} +
```

Comment: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+" ? :(

Comment: Also beware of collisions, or you might end up with `/Users/michael/Downloads/here/test_folder/test_folder/test_folder/...`

Comment: @ghoti `{}` expands to the full, unique name of the current folder, not just `test_folder`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks!, Also if I understand this correctly, `find / -name test_folder -exec mv '{}' /Users/michael/Downloads/here +` will first search entire space for -name 'test_folder' and then will execute command and move that folder with his full name to a selected folder, right? why do i get `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+" ` error when i run it in terminal ?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is you forgot the trailing `+`.

Comment: @chepner, ah, true, I need more coffee.

Comment: Hm. It's less efficient, but try `-exec mv '{}' /Users/michael/Downloads/here \;` instead. Apparently, I've never tried using the `+` form with `{}` anywhere but the final position, where the man page seems to indicate it must occur.