# How to use 'cat' command with -exec in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, exec

I search for some files and I want to replace old content with new content from other files, so I have

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/old -path "*$1" -exec cat /home/new/$1 > {} \;
```

When I execut:

```
> sh find.sh 'blam.php'
```

Problem is the script is creating a file called {} in the same dir with find.sh

Comment: Use `cp` instead ?

Comment: does the file `/home/new/$1` exist ?

Comment: Yes exist, but does nothing

Comment: Why run it under sh when your `#!` if bash?  Try `./find.sh 'blam.php'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find and copy file using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1562102/608639), [How to move or copy files listed by 'find' command in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17368872/608639), [Find and copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5241625/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you get is that `>` is part of shell syntax, and should be literal for find command and syntactic in exec command.

what you are trying to do may be done in two steps

- generating script
- executing the script

.

```
find /home/old -path "*$1" -printf 'cat /home/new/'"$1"' > %p\n' > script.sh
sh script.sh
```

this way allows to check the commands, or using pipe

```
find /home/old -path "*$1" -printf 'cat /home/new/'"$1"' > %p\n' | sh
```

another way less efficient because spwans a shell for each file

```
find /home/old -path "*$1" -exec sh -c 'cat "/home/new/$1" > {}' _ "$1" \;
```

Comment: Good solutions, but can I pass argumnet $1 in -sh c like `-exec sh -c 'echo $1'`, is possible?

Comment: It's safer to pass it as an argument to the `sh` command, rather than embed it in the command: `find ... -exec sh -c 'echo $1' _ "$1"`. There are two different `$1`s here; the one in single quotes is the value of the original shell's (in double quotes).

Comment: So `-exec sh -c 'cat /home/new/$1 > {}' _ "$1" \;`.

Comment: updated from comment

Comment: Hey @chepner , is possible to pass a variable in -exec sh -c? Like `-exec sh -c 'echo $VAR' _ "$VAR"`

Comment: @DobiCaps, the variables are inherited from caller process, `env` can be used to set variable for a process, command passed by arguments : `-exec env VAR=123 sh -c 'echo "$VAR"' \;`, the syntax `_ "$1"` is used to set positional parameters from `sh -c` or `bash -c` command line arguments the `_` is for `$0`

Comment: from  man bash `-c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `> {}` is *not* part of the `find` command. The script is first interpreted by the shell, and the meaning of `>` is handled by the shell before passing the stuff around it as arguments to execute:

```
$ set -- blam.php
$ set -x
$ find /home/old -path "*$1" -exec cat "/home/new/$1" > {} \;
+ find /home/old -path '*blam.php' -exec cat /home/new/blam.php ';'
```

If you want a copy of your file somewhere else, [use `cp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999805/how-to-use-cat-command-with-exec-in-bash/50000455#comment87015516_49999805).