# How to display Html Tabular Data in email Body using Mailx or Mutt

Tags: html, linux, csv, awk

I have a Scenario where i am having one .csv file called Studentdetails.csv

The student details has below following data

```
   Ram,Mumbai,MBA

   Viraj,Delhi,MCA

   Vilas,Kolkata,MMS

   Priya,Agra,BCA
```

My below code convert .csv file to html table format file

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
print  "Content-Type: text/html"
print  "Content-Disposition: inline"
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>Name</TH><TH>City</TH><TH>Course</TH>" 
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
' file-to-convert.csv > StudentDetails.html
```

But my issue is How do i Display this HTML Tabular format in Body of mail 
using mutt or mailx command

*Note: Not as attachment*

Output should be display in mail like below html tabular format

[image]

Comment: Also see [How to embed CSV file in HTML Table Format in E-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58200713/608639).

Comment: And past questions from this user's puppet accounts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58200713/608639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58206219/608639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56541728/608639,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56562435/608639 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/56809228/608639.