# How do I extract or cut particular data from file?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a Scenario where I want to cut only particular data from file.

My file contains the below data:

```
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/abc.xml:262:123:        <NAME ="ABC_BCD">
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/cde.xml:263:ABX:         <NAME ="ABC_BCDXXXXX OBH=TYPE">
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/12a.xml:264:2:456:       <NAME ="ABC_BCD"> 
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/a2c.xml:265:      <NAME ="ABC_BCD">   
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/wed.xml:266:         <NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/as.xml:267:234:    <NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>    
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/ass.xml:268:LMD :        <NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI>
/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/sc.xml:269:22221:        <NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>
```

I need output in below format only excluding duplicate

```
<NAME ="ABC_BCD">
<NAME ="ABC_BCDXXXXX OBH=TYPE">
<NAME ="ABC_BCD"> 
<NAME ="ABC_BCD">   
<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>
<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>    
<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI>
<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>
```

I used the below command it didn't work:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]/+[[:space:]]/+ filename
```

Comment: What happened to `LMD :`? Are the fields separated by a tabulation or by spaces? Is this `grep` output? `LMD means` - it's in your input: `/f/demo/Dummy/g/STSE/ass.xml:268:LMD :`

Comment: Another puppet account... Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58200713/608639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58206219/608639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56541728/608639,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56562435/608639 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/56809228/608639.

Comment: @ this data is fetched from another file using grep if match is found it fetches into another file => this is the above file which contains this output now the issue is need to fetch only data from <Name till end …..  >

Comment: Then why not `grep -h`?

Comment: I used fgrep to match this entire keyword  ` fgrep -n '<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>'  filename >> anotherfile.txt

Comment: why do you use `-n` then?

Comment: @KamilCuk is their any alternate method to match only this entire keyword using grep -h '<NAME ="ABC_BCD" TYPE=LS OBG=UI RML=HJ>'

Comment: I don't understand. `grep -h` or `grep` matches "this entire keyword". (or you mean `grep -x`?) What do you mean by that? Maybe [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) can help. (changed link to the gnu version of grep).

Comment: (@KamilCuk POSIX `grep` has no `-h`. In GNU `grep` it means `--no-filename`.)

Answer (score 0):

> need to fetch only data from `<Name till end ….. >`

So just remove everything in front the `<NAME` if it is constant:

```
sed 's/.*<NAME/<NAME/`
```

You could match also some spaces to make the regex better:

```
sed 's/.*        <NAME/<NAME/`
```